# Transcendental numbers and independence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This may be a stupid question, sorry about that. Can a proposition like "$x\in\mathbb{R}$ is a transcendental number" be independent of ZF?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Define $x$ to be $\pi$ is the continuum hypothesis holds and $17$ otherwise.